# Test if the right mouse button is clicked

Tags: loops, vbscript, mouseevent

What I want to do is: if the Left Mouse button is clicked it needs to be added in a variable.

How do I do this?

```vb
CheckClicked = 0

Do
    If (Left Clicked) Then
        CheckClicked = CheckClicked + 1
    End If
Loop
```

(I'll be adding more code to display this Variable)

Comment: VBScript doesn't support what you're trying to do. Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution.

Comment: Ok, for a certain range of time I want to see how many times the mouse button was clicked. So I came to the conclusion that for every time a mouse button was clicked, it should be added to a variable. Thus I can see for example that the button was clicked 40 times to complete a certain task.

I don't know if this fits what you're trying to ask...

Comment: Where do you want to count the clicks? On a web page/HTA? Some other application? Or just anywhere?

Comment: Anywhere. I've only started learning VBS less than 2 weeks ago, so I'm still new to a lot of things, but I do have experience in programming, not just on-button-click but also on Algorithm programs etc, that's where the loop comes in. So I though that using the Loop I can see if a button is clicked thus it can run an action. But I am also willing to start learning any other language too.

Comment: Not possible with VBScript. AFAIK you need access to the Win32 API so you can hook into window message queues if you want to record mouse clicks anywhere.